# node js async is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

When I try use async it is not defined:

```
async.whilst(func...);
```

Then I import it like so, but async is not a module it says:

```
var async = require('async');
```

So I then use `npm` to install it:

```
npm install async --save
```

But now when I run code I get error and I am not sure if I've installed the correct module:

```
.../node_modules/async/dist/async.js:4960
    iteratee(next);
    ^

TypeError: iteratee is not a function
```

Here is my full code...

```
var async = require('async');
async.whilst(gameloop);

function gameloop()
{
   // I will be adding code here to make it run at 30fps, and use deltatime.
   // This will be a gameloop for the multiplayer game I am creating.
   console.log('yipee!');
   return true;
}
```

I noticed that `yipee!` is being logged once and then the error happened.

Has anyone got an idea on how to fix this one?

Thanks in advance,

David.

**Edit:** Using @nico answer, I got working code: http://pastebin.com/ZCFstqsa

Comment: `async.whilst` expects two arguments. You are only passing one. The [documentation](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#whilst) is pretty clear: *"Repeatedly call `iteratee`, while `test` returns true. Calls `callback` when stopped, or an error occurs."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're missing the second argument called iteratee
http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#whilst
You should do something like this instead
`async.whilst(function allways() { return true; }, gameloop);`

Comment: Thanks for the help. The error is now gone, but the function `gameloop` only gets called once. Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: That's because you need to call a callback when the execution finishes. The gameloop should look like this:
`function gameloop(cb) { console.log("yipee!"); cb();}`

Comment: Thanks, I got the loop working. But there is a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. Is there a way to make it go on forever? Here is my updated code: http://pastebin.com/FAWjvQR8. It only execute for 9ms.

Comment: If you're running under a node.js environment you can call this instead of calling next directly:
`process.nextTick(next);`

Comment: Just after figuring it out too. Thanks a million :)